# Sign of a solution for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I solved two ODEs. To both - I added the $\pm$ sign, because that it's seems right.
Though, WolframAlpha assigns the $\pm$ sign only to the 2nd example. Why?

### 1st example/ODE:

$$
\begin{align*}
& \frac{dy}{dx} - y\cdot \left(2 + \sin x\right) = 0 \\
& \left. \frac{dy}{y} = \left(2 + \sin x\right) dx \quad\middle/ \int \right. \\
& \ln \lvert y \rvert = 2x - \cos x + C,\quad\quad C\in \mathbb R \\
& y = \pm\,e^{2x - \cos x + C} \;\overset{C_2 = e^C}{=}\; \pm \, C_2\cdot e^{2x - \cos x}
\end{align*}
$$
See [solution of WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27-y*%282%20%2B%20sin%28x%29%29%20%3D%200).

### 2nd example/ODE:

$$
\begin{align*}
& \left(1 + e^x\right)\cdot y \cdot y' = e^x \\
& \left. y\,dy = \frac{e^x}{1 + e^x}\,dx \quad\middle/ \int \right. \\
& \frac{y^2}{2} = \ln\left(1 + e^x\right) + C, \quad C\in \mathbb R \\
& y = \pm \sqrt{2\ln\left(1 + e^x\right) + 2\cdot C} \;\overset{C_2 = 2\cdot C}{=}\; \pm \sqrt{2\ln\left(1 + e^x\right) + C_2}
\end{align*}
$$
See [solution of WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%20%2B%20e%5Ex%29*y*%28y%27%29%20%3D%20e%5Ex).

Comment: There is a multiplication by constant in the first one, you can simply hide $\pm$ in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you solve $ln y = k$ you get $y=e^k$. It's a one-to-one relationship.

The reason we write $ln \left| y \right|$ after integrating $\frac 1 y$ is because we are effectively "protecting" the $ln$ function from the possibility that $y$ might be negative (and therefore can't give real logarithm).

As soon as we move on the $\left| y \right|$ becomes unnecessary.

If you start with $ln \left| y \right| =f(x) + c$ you get $y=c'e^{f(x)}$.

When you put in the boundary conditions to find $c'$, it may be that $c'$ turns out to be negative. Therefore no need to put the plus or minus.

When you solve $y^2=k$ you have to give two possible roots $y=\sqrt k$ or $y=-\sqrt k$. This is because squaring is a many-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

That $\int\!\!dy/y$ to $C + \ln |y|$ should be to $C + \ln y$. (WA calculates in $\mathbb{C}$, it seems)

Comment: (1) Can't we combine the constant of the two integrals to a single constant, as I did? (2) As far as I know, the integral of $\frac{1}{y}$ has to be an absolute value of $y$. Why in this case it is different?

Comment: No it is only restricted to avoid imaginary parts, thus staying in $\mathbb{R}$. That is why I remarked that WA calculates in $\mathbb{C}$.